# Pytest data fixture causing function uses no argument 'data' error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, openpyxl, data-driven-tests

I have a Python Selenium testing using at pytest fixture to pass login username and password from a spreadsheet into my test. I am using openpyxl to achieve this.

My test is as follows:

```py
from Base import InitiateDriver
from Pages import LogIn
import pytest
from DataGenerate import DataGen
import openpyxl

@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', DataGen.data_generator())
def test_new():
  browser = InitiateDriver.start_browser()
  login = LogIn.LogInClass(browser)
  login.enter_username(data[0])
  login.enter_password(data[1])
```

I have a DataGen.py file to get the test data from the spreadsheet here:

```py
import openpyxl

def data_generator():
  wk = openpyxl.load_workbook("/users/marklane/Automation/TestData.xlsx")
  sh = wk['login']
  r = sh.max_row
  li = []
  li1 = []
  for i in range(1, r + 1):
    li1 = []
    un = sh.cell(i, 1)
    up = sh.cell(i, 2)
    li1.insert(0, un.value)
    li1.insert(1, up.value)
    li.insert(i - 1, li1)

    print (li)
    return li
```

when running the test I get the following error:

```
latform darwin -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-4.3.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.8.1
rootdir: /Users/marklane/PycharmProjects/test, inifile:
Tests/test_TC_001_ValidateRegistration.py:None 
(Tests/test_TC_001_ValidateRegistration.py)
In test_new: function uses no argument 'data'
collected 0 items / 1 errors

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
__________ ERROR collecting Tests/test_TC_001_ValidateRegistration.py __________

In test_new: function uses no argument 'data'------------------------------- Captured stdout ----------------------- ---------[[u'marklane2001', u'Ipswichtow1!']]
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!
```

As you can see from the error, the data is being found in the spreadsheet but it is not passing that back to 'data' in my selenium lines

Comment: Your test function needs to have `data` as one of its arguments.

Comment: @CharlieClark thanks for the answer. Doesn't me adding the pytest fixture, get the data from Datagen and then pass that into enter username and password lines?

Comment: you need `def test_new(data):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass a parameter to the test itself so that you can use it.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', DataGen.data_generator())
def test_new(data):
  browser = InitiateDriver.start_browser()
  login = LogIn.LogInClass(browser)
  login.enter_username(data[0])
  login.enter_password(data[1])
```

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my answer and added an explanation. Hope to help.